# "à" becoming "de" when the voice goes from active to passive

Tags: grammaire, verbes, syntaxe, passif

The question is on the highlighted clause in this passage from Camus's The Stranger.

> Mais, naturellement, on ne peut pas être toujours raisonnable. D’autres fois, par exemple, je faisais des projets de loi. Je réformais les pénalités. J’avais remarqué que l’essentiel était de donner une chance au condamné. Une seule sur mille, cela suffisait pour arranger bien des choses. Ainsi, il me semblait qu’on pouvait trouver une combinaison chimique dont l’absorption tuerait le patient (je pensais : le patient) neuf fois sur dix. Lui le saurait, c’était la condition. Car en réfléchissant bien, en considérant les choses avec calme, je constatais que ce qui était défectueux avec le couperet, c’est qu’il n’y avait aucune chance, absolument aucune. Une fois pour toutes, en somme, la mort du patient avait été décidée. C’était une affaire classée, une combinaison bien arrêtée, un accord entendu et sur lequel il n’était pas question de revenir. Si le coup ratait, par extraordinaire, on recommençait. Par suite, ce qu’il y avait d’ennuyeux, c’est qu’il fallait que le condamné souhaitât le bon fonctionnement de la machine. Je dis que c’est le côté défectueux. Cela est vrai, dans un sens. Mais, dans un autre sens, j’étais obligé de reconnaître que tout le secret d’une bonne organisation était là. En somme, **le condamné était obligé de collaborer moralement.** C’était son intérêt que tout marchât sans accroc.

**Question**

According to [this dictionary entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/obliger#), the active voice form of *obliger* looks like this:

> obliger quelqu'un **à** faire quelque chose

If so, the Camus clause might have read in the active voice thus:

> L'organisation obligeait le condamné **à** collaborer moralement

(I am not insisting on my choice of subject or the tense for *obliger* there--although if I am totally off the mark, by all means, let me know.)

But when the clause went into the passive, that *à* became *de* (see Camus's original).

Now, the questions.

1. Am I right so far?  (I would be wrong if there was simply another expression:  obliger qn **de** faire qch.)
2. Assuming yes to 1, was it mandatory that *à* should become *de* when the clause went from active to passive?  That is, if *à* remained *à* in the passive, that would have been ungrammatical?
3. Are there some general rules on when *à* should become *de* with the change of voice?  Or what might be some of the other verbs for which this switch takes place?

Comment: Réponse de le TLF :   [À l'actif on emploie de préférence obliger à + inf., obliger de + inf. étant plus usuel au passif.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/obliger). Préférence, pas obligation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Grevisse*** :

> Un certain nombre de verbes construisent l’infinitif complément avec *à* ou *de* indifféremment : c'est l'oreille qui décide.

Il cite : commencer, continuer, contraindre, s'efforcer, s'ennuyer, faire attention, forcer, obliger, solliciter, etc.  Suivent de très nombreux exemples et la remarque suivante :

> Au passif, *contraint*, *forcé*, *obligé* construisent de préférence l’infinitif complément avec *à* quand ils ont réellement une valeur verbale, notamment quand ils ont un complément d'agent ; ils le construisent avec *de* quand ils sont pris adjectivement.

Dans la phrase de Camus *obligé* est employé au passif mais de façon adjectivale :

> En somme, le condamné était obligé de collaborer moralement.

il semble donc se conformer à la tendance générale décrite par Grevisse. Personnellement  l'emploi de *à* ne choquerait pas mon oreille francophone.

<sup>*§ 760, deuxième édition (index *Obliger à* ou *de* + inf.)</sup>

Comment: Grevisse distingue « passif verbal » et « adjectivement ». Ici l'emploi correspond à ce que Grevisse range sous le nom « adjectivement »; « obligé de collaborer » est un attribut, un statut. Le passif verbal « être obligé de collaborer *moralement* par quelqu'un » serait un peu loufoque. Si ça peut parler à certains, l'allemand utiliserait l'auxiliaire *sein* (attributif) et pas *werden* (passif). Camus suit donc tout à fait la tendance générale décrite par Grevisse. Et c'est le contraire qui choquerait une oreille francophone (en tout cas la mienne).

Comment: La réponse pointe exactement l'ambiguité de ces cas. Merci pour la liste !

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Thanks to everyone. Can someone please provide the citation to Grevisse (e.g. section or page number)? I get some idea of the contrast (agency vs. adjectival) from Stéphane Gimenez's comments, but would like to see it explained at greater length if possible.

Comment: J'ai cité et complété votre réponse http://french.stackexchange.com/a/19018/848 en distinguant *avoir obligé quelqu'un à*, et *être obligé de*

Answer (score 2):

1. You are right, one can't say "obliger qqn de faire qqch".
2. With "obliger" usually the passive voice is followed by "de", but it is not the case with the very similar verb "forcer":

> J'ai été obligé de collaborer.
>
> J'ai été forcé à collaborer.

I don't know if "j'ai été obligé à collaborer" is correct or not, but it sounds correct.

3. As shows the precedent example, there is no general rules about that, the usage changes for each verb. If you have to make a choice and you don't know about a precise verb I would recommand you to use "à" as it doesn't sounds as wrong as "de" when you use it at the wrong place.
   See a few more examples:

> J'ai été tenté de collaborer
>
> J'ai été trompé à collaborer
>
> J'ai été pris à collaborer
>
> J'ai été empêché de collaborer

Comment: For the true passive, I much prefer “j'ai été obligé à collaborer par Paul” to “j'ai été obligé de collaborer par Paul”, although “contraint” or “forcé” are much better ways to convey this meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Pour compléter la réponse de *[Laure](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18885/848)*, le Robert donne les usages :

---

- ***Obliger à*** (+ substantif ou infinitif, sinon on emploie *de*)

> La Loi oblige l'homme à quantité d'actes
>
> (forme pronominale) S'obliger à faire

Assujettir par une obligation *d'ordre moral*, (dans les relations humaines, le *à*, sinon *de*) :

> Obliger quelqu'un à faire quelque chose

Mettre dans la nécessité :

...  la version vieillie utilisait *de* :

- > Les persécutions les ont obligé *de* passer dans les Indes (Montesquieu)

... de nos jours :

- > Ses parents l'ont obligé *à* travailler

Pronominal :

> Tu vas m'obliger à me fâcher (familier)
>
> Michèle s'obligea à réciter le De Profundis

... peut être remplacé par *s'imposer de*.

---

- ***Obligé de***

Assujettir par une obligation *d'ordre moral* :

> Ces devoirs nous obligent vis-à-vis de la cité

Assujettir par une obligation *d'ordre juridique* (non suivi de substantif ou d'infinitif):

> Être obligé par contrat de faire telle ou telle chose

---

Albert Camus utilise *obligé **de*** dans le cadre d'un 'assujettissement par obligation' dans deux phrases consécutives.

> ... *j’étais obligé **de** reconnaître* que tout le secret d’une bonne organisation était là. En somme, *le condamné était obligé **de** collaborer* moralement.

Il aurait été maladroit, pour ces deux verbes suivis par un infinitif, d'intercaler un *de* après le premier et un *à* après le second.

En fait, ce n'est pas le sens *obliger **à** + infinitif* (cité en premier plus haut) qui est utilisé par A.Camus,
... mais celui *d'**être** obligé **de** + infinitif*,
... opposé à : ***avoir** obligé quelqu'un **à** + infinitif*.